# hi I am getting error "cannot resolve method locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates();

Tags: android, locationmanager

Sir,
thanks for your help, here is the complete code of my program.
hi I am getting error "cannot resolve method locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates();

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

public Button button;
private TextView textView;
public LocationManager locationmanager;
Context context;
private double lat,lon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationmanager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //error !!!!!!
```

**Error **             locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,0,this);

```
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location!=null)
    {
        lat=location.getLatitude();
        lon=location.getLongitude();
        textView.append("\n lat:"+lat+" lon:"+lon);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First, do not use `"gps"`. Use `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`.

Second, `this` does not match any signature for `requestLocationUpdates()`. `this` is a `View.OnClickListener`, not a `LocationListener` or a `PendingIntent`.

If this code is from an activity or fragment, and that activity or fragment is implementing `LocationListener`, this `MyActivity.this` instead of `this`, where `MyActivity` is the name of the activity or fragment that is implementing `LocationListener`.